# Javascript html broken link mailto/report

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need a javascript or html solution for simple html page.
html link code opens a link, but if link is broken it opens something like an alternative link with code like:

```
<form action="mailto:broken-link@report.com?subject=link.com/dead is broken" method="POST" enctype="text/plain" name="formulier" onsubmit="return;">
```

It this possible or am I thinking about something not realizable?

Comment: AFAIK, From the client size it is not possible. Because, the client cannot determine the validity of the link. I may be wrong.

Comment: if you mean 'broken link' by innaccessible link 
then you can try to use an ajax call to the concerned link , if it got an error than it trigger the error actions

Comment: it must be simple html or javascript, im not allowed to use php/ajax or and other dynamic language

Answer (score 1):

Try something like `mailto:'broken-link@report.com?subject=link.com'` to terminate the possibility of phaser end after a . or -

Comment: This must be the alternative link. But is there a way in html u add an alternative link if primary link does not work?

Comment: not really. You could JS it. Like:
ajax_request("FIRSTURL")->if error(){OTHER URL}

And then: window.location.href="mailto:asdadf";

Short Version:
1. Check via AJAX you get an error
2. if no error-> do first URL else
3. Other URL